# pandas causing NoneType error in matplotlib plt.savefig() and plt.show()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I want to read a csv file using the read_csv method, and then plot the data using matplotlib. However, I cannot seem to create a simple matplotlib plot (even without using the data from the file), after I use pandas to read in some csv data. It gives the error: 'NoneType' object is not callable.

Any idea what's going on here?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

time =  [0,10,20]
vel = [0,1,2]
fig,axes = plt.subplots()
axes.plot(time,vel)
plt.show()
plt.savefig(fname = "pic.png" )
```

I have tried using plot.savefig instead of plot.show() and this produces the same error.

If I move the plotting block of code before the pd.read_csv line, it plots just fine. The error only seems to occur after pandas is used.

This is occuring in Visual Studio. Not occuring in IDLE.

```
Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 384, in __new__
    dtype = numeric.dtype(dtype)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 455, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 436, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 73, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2803, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 132, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 50, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 3020, in draw
    self._unstale_viewLim()
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 776, in _unstale_viewLim
    self.autoscale_view(**{f"scale{name}": scale
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2932, in autoscale_view
    handle_single_axis(
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2895, in handle_single_axis
    x0, x1 = locator.nonsingular(x0, x1)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 1654, in nonsingular
    return mtransforms.nonsingular(v0, v1, expander=.05)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 2880, in nonsingular
    if maxabsvalue < (1e6 / tiny) * np.finfo(float).tiny:
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 387, in __new__
    dtype = numeric.dtype(type(dtype))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please post the complete traceback!

Comment: I should add that this problem is only occuring in Visual Studio. It does not occur in IDLE.

Comment: Traceback now posted

Comment: The traceback does not seem related to the code you posted.

Comment: This is the traceback.
I have solved the issue though. It runs OK if you execute without the debugger. Not sure why the debugger is causing an issue, but it is....